# Adding apple.schema from OS X Lion Server fails

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, openldap, schema

When I try to add apple.schema to my OpenLDAP running on Debian this is the error I get;

```
root@directory:~# ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f apple.schema 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
ldapadd: invalid format (line 1) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 25) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 33) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 44) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 52) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 60) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 68) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 76) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 91) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 99) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 107) entry: ""
... keeps going ... 
... all the way to ... 
ldapadd: invalid format (line 1680) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 1686) entry: ""
ldapadd: invalid format (line 1692) entry: ""
```

I've Googled and gotten nothing. Not sure where else to turn. Any suggestions would be great. Help me reddit, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

psst! Hey you! Yeah you, the confused looking dude! This isn't [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/xwk5e/unable_to_ldapadd_appleschema/)! :-)

---

Also, more importantly, that's not how you add schemas in OpenLDAP ([see the manual](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin22/schema.html)) --
 You want to add an `include /path/to/the/schema/file` directive to the LDAP server's configuration file (`/etc/openldap/slapd.conf`).

Something like

```
    include /etc/openldap/schema/apple.schema
```

will probably do, assuming you put Apple's schema file in the appropriate location...

Comment: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/24648047.jpg

Comment: @AaronCopley maybe later tonight when I'm not amused by it anymore - I mean we have to have some fun in our lives, right?

Comment: .... I feel dumb. Here I go try that now.

Comment: where did you get the schema extensions?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff Easiest place is `/private/etc/openldap/schema/` on a mac, but I believe they're floating around on the Apple website somewhere too

Comment: Ok @voretaq7 so that worked and I didn't get an error when I added the lines but now I get a `8/8/12 4:05:33 PM Workgroup Manager[13753] void -[LoginController gotServerError:forTransaction:](LoginController*, objc_selector*, objc_object*, XSAdminTransaction*): got error kNetworkError from request (null)`

Comment: Thought it might be a dns error and it was. fixed the dns. now this;

`8/8/12 4:11:01.103 PM Workgroup Manager[46635]: -[LoginController gotServerError:forTransaction:]: got error kNetworkError from request (null)`

looks like the same thing I think.